# Docker + Django + ElasticSearch: Failed to establish a connection

Tags: python, django, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm having issues connecting ElasticSearch to Django while *dockerizing* my application. When I try to run my applicatiom using `docker compose`, i get the following error:

```
elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fc59132e890>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused))
```

Before building the containers, I followed this [tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-drf-elasticsearch/), adapting the packages to the versions I wanted. I was able to establish a connection between the Django App and a [single-node cluster running on a docker container](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.10/docker.html). I copied the SSL certificate from the ElasticSearch container to the Django app root, and defined the `ELASTICSEARCH_DSL` on Django settings as:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': ['https://localhost:9200'],
        'http_auth': ('elastic', 'password'),
        'verify_certs': True,
        'ca_certs' : './http_ca.crt',
    },
}
```

After building the containers and creating a *docker-compose.yml*, I didn't find a way to extract the certificate to the Django container. I tried to establish a connection putting `'verify_certs': False` but it didn't work. I tried to find a solution, but most of the time I found people using ElastiSsearch **7.x.x** while I'm using version **8.10.1**.

---

**Python Packages**

- django==4.2.6
- djangorestframework==3.14.0
- django-cors-headers==4.3.0
- elasticsearch==8.10.1
- elasticsearch-dsl==8.9.0
- django-elasticsearch-dsl==8.0
- psycopg2-binary==2.9.9

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:15.4-alpine3.18
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=backend
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=backend
      - POSTGRES_DB=backend_dev

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.10.1
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    container_name: elasticsearch
  
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    container_name: eppa_backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - elasticsearch

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    container_name: eppa_frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
      
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

**settings.py**

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': ['https://localhost:9200'],
        'http_auth': ('elastic', 'password'),
        'verify_certs': False,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `https://localhost:9200` in your app container means you are trying to connect to something that runs on the port 9200 in this container. However, your instance of elasticsearch runs in a different container to which you need to connect. The recommended solution is to create a network and replace `localhost` with `elasticsearch`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:15.4-alpine3.18
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=backend
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=backend
      - POSTGRES_DB=backend_dev
    networks:
      - backend

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:8.10.1
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    container_name: elasticsearch
    networks:
      - backend
  
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    container_name: eppa_backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - backend

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    container_name: eppa_frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - backend
      
volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  backend:
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for more detailed discussion on this topic.

In this case your config file becomes:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': ['https://elasticsearch:9200'],
        'http_auth': ('elastic', 'password'),
        'verify_certs': False,
    },
}
```

In case of certificates, you can disable SSL on this node by adding

```
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=false
```

to the `environment:` of the elasticsearch container.